# How to show $\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \ln\left(\tan x - \sqrt{2 \tan x} + 1\right){d}x = 0 $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

**Problem:** Show that
$$\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \ln\left(\tan x - \sqrt{2 \tan x} + 1\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0 $$
If possible, I would like to use regular single-variable calculus methods, with only substitutions, IBP, partial fractions and so on, which does not involve series manipulation.

Thanks.

Comment: suspect this is false, but might work if you had $2 \sqrt {\tan x} $ instead of $ \sqrt {2 \tan x}. $ In any case, where did you get this?

Comment: Wolfram and Maple say this is true. I need to prove this to compute $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\left(x^2 - 1\right)\arctan(x^2)}{1 + x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x $$.

Comment: @user149844: The value to your integral in the comment is $ \ln  ( 2 ) \sqrt{2}\pi $

Comment: But how could I deduce this value? In an equivalent manner, one could show that $$\int_{0}^{\pi /2} \ln \left(\tan x + \sqrt{2 \tan x} + 1\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = -2\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\ln\left( \cos x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = -2\int_{0}^{\pi /2} \ln\left(\sin x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \pi \ln 2 $$. Just add and subtract $ \ln\left(\tan x +\sqrt{2 \tan x} + 1\right) $ to the integrand and use logarithms properties, but I do not know if this makes the problem someway easier.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305736/int-0-infty-frac-ln-left1x-sqrt2x-right1x2-dx?noredirect=1

Answer (score 6):

Substitute $t^2=\tan x$, together with $t^4+1=(t^2-\sqrt2 t+1)(t^2+\sqrt2 t+1) $
\begin{align}
I=&\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \ln\left(\tan x - \sqrt{2 \tan x} + 1\right)\,dx \\
=&\int_0^\infty \frac{2t\ln(t^2-\sqrt2 t+1)}{t^4+1}dt\\
=&\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln(t^4+1)}{t^4+1}\overset{y=t^2}{dt}
 + \frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \underset{=J}{\frac{t\ln\frac{t^2-\sqrt2 t+1}{t^2+\sqrt2 t+1}}{t^4+1}}dt\tag1\\
\end{align}
Further decompose the integral $J$ as follows
\begin{align}
J=& \ \frac1{\sqrt2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overset{y=\sqrt2t-1}{\frac{\ln(t^2-\sqrt2t+1)}{t^2-\sqrt2t+1}}+ \overset{y=\sqrt2t+1}{ \frac{\ln(t^2+\sqrt2t+1)}{t^2+\sqrt2t+1}}-\overset{y=\frac{t-1/t}{\sqrt2}}{\frac{(1+t^2)\ln(t^4+1)}{t^4+1}}\ dt\\
=& \ 2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln \frac{y^2+1}2}{y^2+1}dy
 - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln (2(y^2+1))}{y^2+1}dy
 =2 \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\ln \frac{y^2+1}8}{y^2+1}dy
\end{align}
Plug $J$ into (1) to arrive at
\begin{align}
I =\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(y^2+1)}{y^2+1}dy
 + \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\ln \frac{y^2+1}8}{y^2+1}dy
 =\ \frac32 \int_0^\infty  \frac{\ln \frac{y^2+1}4}{y^2+1}dy=0
\end{align}