# How to show that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x} -\sqrt{2})\ dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How can I show that

> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x} -\sqrt{2})\ dx=0$$

I saw this integral on AoPS, and one person provides a solution:

Let
$$I:=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \ln(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt 2 ) \ dx, \ \ \ \ \ J:=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \ln(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}+\sqrt 2 ) \ dx.$$I show that
$$I=0, \ \ \ \ \ J=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$We have
$$I+J=\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln(\tan x+\cot x) \ dx=\int_0^{\pi/4}(\ln 2-\ln(\sin(2x)) \ dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}(\ln 2-\ln(\sin x)) \ dx$$$$=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x) \ dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$Next is to compute $I-J.$ To avoid the mess, as much as we can, we put $\tan x = t^2$ to get
$$I=\int_0^1\ln\left(t+\frac{1}{t}-\sqrt{2}\right)\frac{2t}{t^4+1} \ dt, \ \ \ \ \ J=\int_0^1\ln\left(t+\frac{1}{t}+\sqrt{2}\right)\frac{2t}{t^4+1} \ dt$$and changing $t$ to $1/t$ gives
$$I=\int_1^{\infty}\ln\left(t+\frac{1}{t}-\sqrt{2}\right)\frac{2t}{t^4+1} \ dt, \ \ \ \ \ \ J=\int_1^{\infty}\ln\left(t+\frac{1}{t}+\sqrt{2}\right)\frac{2t}{t^4+1} \ dt.$$Thus
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\ln\left(t+\frac{1}{t}-\sqrt{2}\right)\frac{t}{t^4+1} \ dt, \ \ \ \ \ \ J=\int_0^{\infty}\ln\left(t+\frac{1}{t}+\sqrt{2}\right)\frac{t}{t^4+1} \ dt$$and hence, since $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t\ln t}{t^4+1} \ dt=0$ (just change $t$ to $1/t$ to see that), we get
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t\ln(t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1)}{t^4+1} \ dt, \ \ \ \ \ J=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t\ln(t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1)}{t^4+1} \ dt.$$Therefore
$$I-J=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t}{t^4+1}(\ln(t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1)-\ln(t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1)) \ dt. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$We now use integration by parts with $\frac{t}{t^4+1} \ dt=dv, \ \ \ \ln(t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1)-\ln(t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1)=u.$ Then
$$v=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(t^2), \ \ \ du=\frac{2\sqrt{2}(t^2-1)}{t^4+1} \ dt$$and so $(3)$ becomes
$$I-J=-\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^2-1}{t^4+1}\tan^{-1}(t^2) \ dt=-\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^2-1}{t^4+1}\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{s^2t^4+1} \ ds \ dt=-\sqrt{2}\int_0^1\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^2(t^2-1)}{(t^4+1)(s^2t^4+1)} \ dt \ ds$$$$=-\sqrt{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-s^2}\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{s^2t^2+1}{s^2t^4+1} \ dt-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{t^4+1} \ dt \right)ds.$$So changing $t$ to $t/\sqrt{s}$ in $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{s^2t^2+1}{s^2t^4+1} \ dt$ gives
$$I-J=-\sqrt{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-s^2}\left((\sqrt{s}-1)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^2}{t^4+1} \ dt+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}-1\right)\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^4+1}\right)ds$$$$=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-s^2}\left(\sqrt{s}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}-2\right)ds=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)$$Now $(1)$ follows from $(2)$ and $(4).$

This is an elegant solution, but I wonder if there are other ways to solve the integral.

Comment: I think sub $x=\frac{\pi}{4}-y$ would help here.

Comment: Have you tried exploiting symmetry ? Also, $$\sqrt2 = \dfrac1{\sqrt2} + \dfrac1{\sqrt2} = \sin(\pi/4) + \sin(\pi/4) = \cos(\pi/4) + \cos(\pi/4) =$$ $$= \sin(\pi/4) + \cos(\pi/4).$$

Comment: I don't quite see the symmetry for this problem.

Comment: It's a nice problem but I feel that upvotes are unecessay here as the OP has pasted in a solution to a question asked and answered on AoPS.

Comment: AoPS provides one solution, and I am seeking other methods.

Comment: @Larry I know that, however writing out somebody else's question and answer with your actual question the last few words does not, IMO, constitute a good question.

Comment: Ok, I will take notice of that next time.

Comment: Note that
\begin{equation*}
 I-J =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{t\,\ln(t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1)}{t^4+1}\, dt =f(\sqrt{2})-f(0) 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
 f(s)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{t\,\ln(t^2-st+1)}{t^4+1}\, dt.
\end{equation*}
Furthermore
\begin{equation*}
 f'(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{-t^2}{(t^4+1)(t^2-st+1)}\, dt=\pi\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{4-s^2}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4-s^2}}\right)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
 f(\sqrt{2})-f(0)=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}f'(s)\, ds = -\dfrac{\pi\ln 2}{2}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303483/integral-int-0-frac-pi4-ln-sinx-cosx-sqrt-sin2xdx/3305305#3305305) of mine, I was able to show that $\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \ln\left(1+\tan x + \sqrt{2\tan x} \right) dx = -\frac{G}{2} +\frac{\pi \ln 2}{2}$ by complex method. Combining with $\int_0^{\frac\pi 4} \ln (\tan x) dx = -G$, we can see that $J = \frac{\pi \ln 2}{2}$ and $I = (I+J)-J = 0$.

Comment: $@$Song Interesting technique.

Answer (score 3):

With $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\ln({\tan x})dx=0$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x} -\sqrt{2})\overset{x\to \frac\pi2-x}{dx}\\
=& \ \frac12 \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\ln(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x} -\sqrt{2})\ dx\\
=&\ \frac12\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\ln({\tan x}-\sqrt{2\tan x} +1)\ dx \\
=& \ \frac12\cdot \frac32 \int_0^\infty  \frac{\ln \frac{y^2+1}4}{y^2+1}dy=0
\end{align}
where the $y$-integral in the last step results from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4448519/686284).